# VB.NET Trouble with Inheritance

Tags: vb.net

I am running a web server using VB.net and I have a bunch of pages that need to utilize similar functionality, so I was thinking of creating a shared base class that incorporates all of this shared functionality. I created a file call it `SharedBaseClass.vb`, and I also have a class that should inherit from this class, `SubClass.aspx.vb`. The Top few lines of the the parent class look like this:

```
Partial Class SharedBaseClass
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
```

And of the child class that should inherit:

```
Partial Class SubClass
    Inherits SharedBaseClass
```

Then at the top of the `SubClass.aspx` file it looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Main_SA.master" AutoEventWireup="false" Src="SubClass.aspx.vb" Inherits="SubClass" %>
```

Assume that all of these files are located in the same directory.

But when I try to run this, I get an error:
Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'SharedBaseClass' is not defined.
And then the highlighted error is on the line that reads: `Inherits SharedBaseClass`

I've also tried importing the file to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other item to check, which isn't as big an issue in VB.Net as it is in C# is to make sure that if you have a `Namespace` specified in `SharedBaseClass`, that the same `Namespace` is specified for the inherited classes.

Comment: I got it. it turns out it was an issue with where my App_Code folder was being stored

Answer (score 2):

The class SharedBaseClass must be `public` and  code file `SharedBaseClass.vb` must be located under `App_Code` folder.

```
Public Partial Class SharedBaseClass
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
....
```

Comment: You should remove the Shared statement from the class since that is not allowed in VB.Net.

Comment: @competent_tech - Thanks budy! It should be partial, not a shared.

Comment: still is giving me the same issue after I make the base class public. I'm actually editing this code outside of Microsoft Visual Studio. Is it possible that this is the issue? Does visual studio automate importing files and creating bundles that are used when the code is compiled?

Comment: @ecbtln - The code file SharedBaseClass.vb must be placed inside the App_Code folder in your web-app.

Comment: thought that would work, still not sure what's wrong. do I need to import it as well? or is it automatically imported?

Comment: @ecbtln - Code file placed inside App_Code will be compiled automatically by asp.net compiler and no need to import. Be sure that the type(class) must be public. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx

Comment: hmm ok guess that pretty much forces me to use visual studio. was hoping i'd be able to edit an already existing project using a simple text editor